# Working with PDF and CDF

Tags: statistics

I have a question about how to find the range of a pdf function.
For instance, I have got this probably which says that x is a continuous random variable with pdf fx(x)=4x^3. I need to find the pdf of y=πx^2.
How do I find the range of my pdf fx(x)?

Thank you!

Comment: How can someone give you the pdf without the support? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Since PDFs are non-negative, so is $X$. A constant $a\ge0$ exists for which $X$ has cdf $F_X(x):=x^4-a^4$, with range $[a,\,(1+a^4)^{1/4}]$. Knowing the psychology of question-askers, they probably expect you to take $a=0$. Since $P(Y\le y)=P(X\le\pi^{-1/2}y^{1/2})$, $Y$ has pdf $\frac12\pi^{-1/2}y^{-1/2}f_X(\pi^{-1/2}y^{1/2})=\frac{2y}{\pi^2}$ on the range of $Y$, which is $[\pi a^2,\,\pi(1+a^4)^{1/2}]$.